# How to download then again upload blob in Javascript using Fetch Api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

In the following snippet downloading works as expected but uploading is not working, getting a `HTTP 500` response. The issue isn't backend as it works in Postman or equivalent.
What could be the issue?

```
 return fetch('url', {
  method: 'GET',
}).then((response) => {

  //upload

  if (response.status === 200) {
    let blob = response.blob();
    return fetch('url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      },
      body: blob,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
    });
  }
  
});
```

Comment: "not working" is not an error or adequate problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include any errors you receive (as text).

Comment: If it's not happening when you use Postman, then there must be some setting you're using in Postman that you're not using in `fetch`.  [Read up on the options available for `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) and compare them with what you're providing to Postman. That's something you can do without us.

Comment: Definitely, I can do without you. Have a good day. @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 0):

Try using form data,

```
if (response.status === 200) {
    let blob = response.blob();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.set('file', blob);
    return fetch('url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      body: blob,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
    });
  }
```

Comment: it doesnt stilll getting 500 error, but itisnt server because I am able to upload with postman

Comment: Check the content type and post data in postman and try to compare with your fetch request

Comment: ´response.blob()´ returns a Promise. You need to pass ´body: form´ and perhaps not specifying headers to allow automatic form boundary to be added.